# ADF Track Pipeline Changes

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is that possible to see that changes and whom made the changes to the ADF pipeline? In QA some pipeline changes are made and the code has been published. IS that possible to track?

Comment: Refer the [microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control) on Source control in Azure Data Factory

Answer (score 0):

To track the changes in Azure Data Factory, configure git repository with GitHub or Azure-repos.

- This will help to track the changes done in Pipeline.
- Also, you can revert the changes done in code and bring back the previous versions of code.
- You cannot track who made changes directly in ADF. Instead, you can configure the code-review process and allow few members to make changes in code via git and only limited members can publish those changes to data factory.

Reference: [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control) on Source control in Azure Data Factory